# No event Delegation of UIButton with CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios

I am setting up UIButton to fall on the iPad screen in vertical direction setting up the code something like

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
theAnimation.repeatCount=1e100;
theAnimation.autoreverses=NO;
for (UIButton *vbtn in flakesArray) {
    //vbtn.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
    [vbtn addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(aMethodTesting:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    CGPoint p = vbtn.center;
     startypos = p.y;
    NSLog(@"%f",startypos);
     endypos = self.view.frame.size.height;
    p.y = endypos;
    NSLog(@"%f",endypos);
    vbtn.center = p;
    //float timeInterval = ((Float32)(animationDurationMax-animationDurationMin)*(Float32)random()/(Float32)RAND_MAX);
    theAnimation.duration=200;
    theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-startypos];
    [vbtn.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"transform.translation.y"];
    [self.view addSubview:vbtn];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:vbtn]; 
}
```

but this code would not allow my UIButton to invoke the method aMethodTesting: any help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Does your aMethodTesting really take the sender as an argument? If not, remove the :
2. It should be UIButton *vbtn (It is a pointer)

Please format your code as code, it is quite unreadable now.

Comment: I tried removing : but it is of no help.And yes my code reads for ( UIButton *vbtn in flakesArray) . Any more help?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, this is editing to your code.This is falling single button. You can use this for multiple.

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation = [CABasicAnimation    animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];

theAnimation.repeatCount=1e100;
theAnimation.autoreverses=NO;
float startypos = 1.0f;
float endypos=480.0f;
float animationDurationMax = 500.0f;
float animationDurationMin = 50.0f;
UIButton *vbtn = (UIButton *)sender;
//for ( UIButton *vbtn in flakesArray)
{
    vbtn.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
    [vbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethodTesting:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    CGPoint p = vbtn.center;
    startypos = p.y;
    NSLog(@"%f",startypos);
    endypos = self.view.frame.size.height;
    p.y = endypos;
    NSLog(@"%f",endypos);
    vbtn.center = p;
    float timeInterval = (animationDurationMax-animationDurationMin);//random()/RAND_MAX);
    theAnimation.duration=2;
    theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-startypos];
    [vbtn.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"transform.translation.y"];
    [self.view addSubview:vbtn];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:vbtn];
}
```